# Return cell value with an address

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a cell adress after a find fonction :

```
YOLO = Worksheets("Adobe Reader").Range("A1:A500").Find("YOLO").Address 'Exemple : $A$131
```

And when I try to show the Value of the adress range, it show only the adress :

```
Worksheets("Caracteristiques").Range("B1").Value = Worksheets("Adobe Reader").Range("YOLO").Value
```

In range B1 i have $A$131. How can I get the cell value instead ?

Comment: I don't get the sense of this. If you search for "YOLO" then of course the value of the found cell is "YOLO" you already know that, you don't need a code for that.

Comment: YOLO is one word in a sentence in one cell among a lot of cell in column A sheet Adobe Reader. I want to find the cellule who get YOLO (with Find fonction who is working) and then in B1 sheet Caractéristiques show all the sentence, and not the adress of the cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing it slightly differently like below:

```
Dim YOLO As Range
Set YOLO = Worksheets("Adobe Reader").Range("A1:A500").Find(What:="YOLO" LookAt:=xlPart) 
'or LookAt:=xlWhole if the full content of the cell
If Not YOLO is Nothing Then Worksheets("Caracteristiques").Range("B1").Value = YOLO.Value 
'or to get the address (YOLO.Address)
```

Comment: I highly recommend to use `xlPart` in `Find(What:="YOLO", LookAt:=xlPart)` otherwise Excel will use the method that was last used (and you will never know which one this was). For details see: [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)